# Que parámetros debo de incluir en el script de python si quiero que se ejecute automáticamente al iniciar con Windows ya en .exe?

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un reloj digital con python pero quiero que se inicie juntamente con Windows es decir, ya teniendo el script en .exe  que se ejecute automáticamente cuando se encienda el ordenador para que el usuario no tenga que estar dándole click a la aplicación y que sea de manera automática su inicio

Comment: Hola Alex, has intentado algo? Algún código de ejemplo? Yo no estoy seguro que se pueda hacer desde el script pero probablemente si. En la [pagina de soporte de microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/4026268/windows-10-change-startup-apps) explican como hacerlo desde Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes un par de **opciones**:

1. Que se ejecute directamente el script
2. Convertirlo a `.exe` con alguna herramienta

Asumo que tu usuario puede tener el ordenador sin configuración idónea y que, por tanto, no tendrá python u/o las librerías necesarias.

**Solución:**

Antes que nada deberías **convertir proyecto de pyhon a un `.exe`** usando [cx_Freeze](https://marcelotduarte.github.io/cx_Freeze/), [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) o [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/) (entre otros). Dejo [aquí](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/generar-archivo-ejecutable-con-cx_freeze-pyinstaller-y-py2exe/) una guía de los 3.

Ten en cuenta que algunas librerías emplean gráficos dependientes del sistema operativo, es decir, si conviertes en Mac sólo será usable en Mac, si conviertes en es en Windows sólo ejecutará en Windows, etc. Revisa que el `.exe` funcione correctamente en tu sistema "cliente".

Una vez hecho esto ya casi has terminado, es hora de **configurar el inicio automático**. Para ello puedes dejárselo al usuario o configurar un instalador.

Si se lo dejas al usuario debes indicarle como emplear o ubicar el programa. Personalmente recomiento usar [Autostart-app](https://pypi.org/project/Autostart-app/), pero en algunos sistemas resulta incluso más sencillo añadir el ejecutable a la carpeta de auto inicio (por ejemplo en Windows: `C:\Users\current_user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`)

Por otra parte, si realizas un instalador, lo único que deberás hacer es programarle que ubique el fichero correctamente o que ejecute el Autostart-app.

Espero que sea útil ;)