# Hacer que un programa se agregue al inicio de Windows, después de ejecutarlo por primeva vez (Incluido dentro del .py)

Tags: python, python-3.x

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme, quiero que mi programa, una vez se ejecute por primera vez, ya  convertido a (.exe) se añada automaticamente al inicio de Windows, para que cada vez que inicie posteriormente el ordenador se inicie automáticamente en segundo plano.

Se que se puede implementar algunas soluciones como crear un instalador, hacerlo de forma manual con el programador de tareas o algunas otras soluciones alternativas que se plantean aqui:

- [Que parámetros debo de incluir en el script de python si quiero que se ejecute automáticamente al iniciar con Windows ya en .exe?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392592/que-par%c3%a1metros-debo-de-incluir-en-el-script-de-python-si-quiero-que-se-ejecute-a)

Pero lo que yo quiero saber es si se puede implementar el código necesario para esto dentro del archivo (.py) mediante alguna función, de forma que ya una vez convertido a (.exe) lo ejecutes la primera vez y ya se añada automáticamente al inicio de Windows y se inicie solo cada vez que inicies el pc. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los programas que se ejecutan al inicio se encuentran en una carpeta específica, lo que podrías hacer es mover tu programa a ese path y siempre hacer la revisión de si el programa se encuentra alli

Comment: Ya, esa opcion la había contemplado, pero yo lo que quiero es que el usuario no tenga que hacer absolutamente nada, que una vez que arranques el programa una vez este se añada al inicio de windows automaticamente, creo que es posible, porque yo a veces he instalado un programa y automaticamente se ha añadido al inicio, si encuentro algo lo pongo por aqui.

Comment: Yo nunca dije que el usuario lo tenía que hacer, esa operación la puede hacer el propio script con ayuda del módulo `os`

Comment: Ya, supongo que se podrá, pero mis conocimientos de Python, son limitados, no soy programador profesional ni nada de ese estilo, mas bien soy amateur, si encuentras algun ejemplo con el uso del módulo (os) y lo quieres subir aqui, te lo agradeceria, otra solución posible que estoy mirando es mediante el módulo (win32api) y (win32con),  si cuencuentro algo lo dejo por aquí, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

encontré una manera de solucionar tu duda con un par de métodos, moviendo el mismo archivo a la carpeta inicio predeterminada en Windows 10, talvez no es la mejor manera, no soy un gran experto, pero esta es una manera creativa y te explicaré como hacerlo:

**1**.Necesitaremos un par de librerías:

```
import psutil, shutil
```

-**psutil**: la usaremos para saber el nombre de usuario del dispositivo con el metodo *users()*:

```
psutil.users()
```

-**shutil**: la usaremos para mover el archivo con el método *move()*:

```
shutil.move("archivo.txt", "ruta/archivo.txt")
```

**2**.Luego de haber importado las librerías gestionamos el nombre de usuario:

```
import shutil, psutil

info_usuarios = psutil.users()
usuario = info_usuarios[0][0]
```

Te explicaré rápidamente esa parte de código:

**psutil.users()** devuelve una lista en donde se encuentra información acerca de los usuarios, si solo existe un usuario devuelve algo así:

> > [suser(name='usuario1', terminal='pts/2', host='localhost', started=1515272211.0, pid=1689)]

Si existen 2 usuarios algo así:

> > [suser(name='usuario1', terminal='pts/2', host='localhost', started=1515272211.0, pid=1689),
> > suser(name='usuario2', terminal='pts/3', host='localhost', started=1515272211.0, pid=2314)]

Puedes observar que primero hay una lista y luego una tupla para cada usuario, entonces para identificar el primer usuario y guardarlo en una variable, tomaremos el primer elemento de la lista devuelta (*primera tupla*) y posteriormente el primer elemento de la primera tupla (*nombre de usuario*), por esa razón lo usamos de esta manera --> **usuario = info_usuarios[0][0]**

**3**.A continuación estableceremos una variable en la cual unimos el nombre de usuario con la ruta predeterminada de la carpeta **inicio** en Windows 10, claro, agregándole el nombre del archivo al final:

```
ruta_inicio = "C:/Users/" + usuario + "/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/startup/programa.exe"
```

**4**.Hora de usar el método para mover el archivo:

```
shutil.move("programa.exe", ruta_inicio)
```

Y listo, una vez el archivo esté en la carpeta **inicio** se ejecutará cada vez que inicie el dispositivo.

Código completo:

```
import shutil, psutil

info_usuarios = psutil.users()

usuario = info_usuarios[0][0]

ruta_inicio = "C:/Users/" + usuario + "/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/startup/programa.exe"

try:
    shutil.move("programa.exe", ruta_inicio)

except Exception as error:

    print(error)
    input("presione enter para continuar...")
    pass

'''
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
--------- codigo del programa ----------
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
'''
```

Por cierto el **try** y el **except** son para que el programa intente mover el archivo, si este no pudo, te mostrará el error y la información del porqué sucedió ese error.

Si por alguna razón tu ruta de la carpeta **inicio** es diferente, presiona '**Windows** + **R**', luego introducir "**shell:startup**", luego **enter** y este te llevará a tu carpeta de inicio de tu Windows y podrás ver como es la ruta.

En caso de que tengas alguna duda u problema, déjame un comentario, espero y te funcione.

Comment: Hey, muchas gracias por hacer mi comentario una respuesta (y muy buena) +1

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, @maxin739, intentaré inplementarlo cuando tenga un rato libre a ver si me funciona, y os cuento, muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo he probado y me funciona perfecto, @maxin739, la unica pega es que he tenido que meterlo dentro de una funcion para poder utilizarlo y el codigo del programa en si, en otra función, he tenido que utillizar multiprocesamiento para que se ejecuten los 2 a la vez. ¿Se podria hacer sin utilizar multiprocesamiento? gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Hector9999 La función que mueve el archivo debe ir antes que el resto de código, luego de codificarla, afuera de la función se llama esa misma, se hace el proceso y ya luego comenzaría con la idea original del programa , no creo que haya necesidad de usar multiprocesamiento.

Comment: @maxin739 intentaré probar mañana como dices, a ver si consigo hacer que funcione y te cuento por aquí.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @maxin739, funciona perfectamente, y és al final la que he utilizado, de todas maneras, añado otra respuesta que he encontrado, por si alguien quiere probar a ver si funciona, aunque parece algo más compleja y no se si funcionara.

> Ejecutar aplicación o script al iniciar Windows

```
from win32api import (GetModuleFileName, RegCloseKey, RegDeleteValue,
                      RegOpenKeyEx, RegSetValueEx)
from win32con import HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KEY_WRITE, REG_SZ

SUBKEY = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"

def run_at_startup_set(appname, path):
    """
    Sets the registry key to run at startup.
    """
    key = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SUBKEY, 0, KEY_WRITE)
    RegSetValueEx(key, appname, 0, REG_SZ, path)
    RegCloseKey(key)

def run_script_at_startup_set(appname, script):
    path = "%s %s" % (GetModuleFileName(0), script)
    run_at_startup_set(appname, path)

def run_at_startup_remove(appname):
    """
    Removes the run-at-startup registry key.
    """
    key = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SUBKEY, 0, KEY_WRITE)
    RegDeleteValue(key, appname)
    RegCloseKey(key)
```